# Print the selected area into 1 Page PDF

Tags: vba, pdf

In continuation with the below code, how to fit the print area into one page?

```
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "c:\Book1.pdf", Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you exported, its not possible anymore.

What I do, is I change the `PageSetup` with  `.FitToPagesWide = 1` (*before* exporting)

```
 With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
End With

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="c:\Book1.pdf", _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

Comment: Great news @Amith.B! Then are you aware of [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much better solution, it makes sure to not print any extra comments you have and the selection is printed to scale on one page in a PDF format. You will also receive a dialog box asking you where to save which will work flawlessly. The beautiful part about this whole code is look at where it says pdf and change out the format to what you want and it should save to your desired format:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim file_name As Variant
file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Adobe PDF File_ (*.pdf), *.pdf")
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintComments = -4142

    Range("B2:X41").Select
    Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=file_name, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```